# How to change the way UINavigationBar show the attributed color?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uikit, uinavigationbar

In cocoa touch 
the navigation bar, have like a built in functionality to add gradiency to the color i'm applying to it, 
for example if i'm setting a red color, it will give a gradient from red, to a whiter-red color.

What are the ways to change that?

1. using the properties of the
   navigation bar.
   (stopgradient,setbackgroundImage...
   or anything to override it)
2. To at least imitate it. Since we know it's definitely
   related to lookandfeel defined by
   Apple, what is the actual way of the
   calculation, so maybe i can simulate
   it with the designer, and give him
   like a program for him to preview
   the colors before sending it to me.
   I don't mind a link to such a page
   that describes all that.
3. the forced way, override the paint
   of the navigationbar?

thanks a lot.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Cocoa.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure from your question whether you already know about the `tintColor` property on UINavigationBar, but that's the officially supported way to change the color. See the documentation [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationBar_Class/Reference/UINavigationBar.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UINavigationBar/tintColor).

If you want your designer to be able to see what it looks like he can use Interface Builder and drag a UINavigationBar onto a view and change its tint.

Comment: yeah, i know about the tint color, and that's what i'm using to change the color, but there's this white light to make look 3d that i want to get rid of, or at least to do the gradient from red to color2 which is not white.
oh and the designer is a girl, with illustrator only.So are you sure it's good idea (sssssshhhhh... especially that it took a couple of years at university for illustrator)?

Comment: Well in that case you are going to have to subclass and implement drawRect where you fill your own custom gradient. I'm not sure how well the standard UINavigationBar etc. support this however.